# Vim: Moving cursor to the end of a block

Tags: vscodevim

Given that I am in the middle of a code block, I want to go to the end of the block without using `h`,`j`,`k`,`l`.

I am looking for similar behaviour with `%`, which will also work when my cursor is somewhere in the code block.

Example:

[image]

I want to move the cursor to where to the line `22`, where Container block ends.

I would appreciate for your help, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the following commands:

```
]) -> Move the cursor to the closed closing of first bracket '('
]} -> Move the cursor to the closed closing of second bracket '{'
```

As you are looking for the nearest first bracket, the first one should work for your case.